# Comparing char* to string without strcmp

Tags: c

I am trying to compare contents of char* to a string. I am able to print out the content but not able to compare them.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int input(char * x){
    int i,j = 0;
    char myArray[10];
    x = myArray;
    scanf("%s", x);

    for(x; *x !='\0'; x++){
        if(*x == "ne"){
            printf("%d",1);
            return 0;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `if(*x == "ne")` is comparing the `char` `*x` to the address of `"ne"`.  Code needs to compare `char` to `char`, one at a time.

Comment: char * actually represents the memory address of the first character in each string. So you don't really want to be comparing the values of the pointers, but the contents they point to.

Comment: @chux: I have been trying to do that. I have looked at articles online and they suggested me to use a loop. I understand I need to compare each character but I am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's code nicely iterates through `x` ...

```
for(x; *x !='\0'; x++){
```

... but then attempts to compare each `char` of `x` to the address of `"ne"`.

```
if(*x == "ne"){  // bad code
```

To compare the strings pointed by 2 `char *`, could make your own `strcmp()`.
Note the real `strcmp()` returns 0 when strings match or positive or negative values depending on which is "greater".  OP's seems to only need an equal or not comparison.

```
// Return 1 if the same
int my_streq(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  while (*s1 == *s2 && *s1) {
    s1++;
    s2++;
  }
  return *s1 == *s2;
}


int readinput(char * x) {
  ....
  if (my_streq(x, "ne")) {
    printf("%d",1);
    return 0;
  }
  ....
}
```